# Take out each digit in a user input integer, and display the conversion of each digit to it's hexadecimal value?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, function, hex, decimal

I am doing a program where I have the user enter a decimal value, and the user has the option to either convert it to binary, octal, or hex. I got the binary and octal conversion down, but I want to do the hex conversion. I know, in C++ all I would need to do to convert is:

```
int convert = 78
cout << hex << convert << endl;

Output:
4e
```

However that's not what I am handling. I want to show it so that the program will take out each digit in the integer, and show that digit being converted to hex. For example, I will show you how I did it with my binary conversion.

```
//Variable declaration
int b;
int d;
char decision;

//Declare function prototype
int convertDecimalToBinary(int);

//Welcome the user. Then ask them to enter a decimal value. The input will   be held in int d.
cout << "Welcome to The Converter!"; 

decimal:
cout << "\n" << "Please enter a decimal value: ";
cin >> d;

conversion:
//Ask the user if they want to conver this to Binary, Octal, or Hexadecimal
cout << "\n\nDo you want to convert " << d
    << " to Binary (b), Octal (o), or Hexadecimal (h)?: ;
cin >> decision;

//If the user wanted to do a binary conversion to the inputted decimal value
if (decision == 'b')
{
    //Call the convertDecimalToBinary function, and set the value of it equal to b.
    b = convertDecimalToBinary(d);

    //Output the conversion
    cout << "\n\nThe decimal value you inputted, " << d << ", in binary: " << b << endl;
}

 /*
    The convertDecimalToBinary function, this will take the user input (a decimal value) and convert it to binary.
    @param decimal, the decimal value the user inputted
    @return binary, the converted binary value.
*/
int convertDecimalToBinary(int decimal)
{
    //Declare variables for the function
    int x = decimal;
    int i = 0;
    int a = 1;
    int remainder;
    int binary = 0;
    int step;

    //Do the binary conversion until x=0
    while (x != 0)
    {   
        //Do the what was just explained. Set int step equal to x/2, set int remainder to x%2. Include counter addition, i++.
        i++;
        step = x / 2;
        remainder = x % 2;
        cout << "| Stage " << i << ": " << x << " / 2 = " << step << " | Remainder: " << remainder << " | " << endl;

        //This is to prevent and infinite loop
        x /= 2;

        //This will print out the remainder digits and form it in decimal
        //We need to do last remainder first, to first remainder last.
        binary += remainder * a;
        a *= 10;
    }

    //Return the conversion
    return binary;
}
```

And here is a screenshot of the output:

```
Output:

Please enter a decimal value: 109


Do you want to convert 109 to Binary (b), Octal (o), or Hexadecimal (h)?: b

| Stage 1: 109 / 2 = 54 | Remainder: 1 |
| Stage 2: 54 / 2 = 27 | Remainder: 0 |
| Stage 3: 27 / 2 = 13 | Remainder: 1 |
| Stage 4: 13 / 2 = 6 | Remainder: 1 |
| Stage 5: 6 / 2 = 3 | Remainder: 0 |
| Stage 6: 3 / 2 = 1 | Remainder: 1 |
| Stage 7: 1 / 2 = 0 | Remainder: 1 |


The decimal value you inputted, 109, in binary: 1101101
```

Octal is pretty similar to this honestly. But you see the step-by-step like way. I want to be able to pull a digit out, and be able to convert that digit to hexadecimal. Show that digit and what it's hex value is, and go to the next digit. Once all the digits are converted, go back to the main and display the hex! Is that possible, and if so how can I make that possible (at least help me start it up if you could). I appreciate it guys!

Comment: Do exactly the same way - divide by 16 and use reminder. What is the problem?

Comment: Vote to reopen.  OP is interested in performing the conversion manually, not using `%x`  or `std::hex`.

Comment: Hint: create a string instead of a number.

Comment: @dbush They should give a good reasoning why they want to do that reinventing the wheel, or why their professor/teacher wants them to do it with a different implementation. If this question was asked for learning purposes, there are sure better ways to ask that question providing a [MCVE] and showing debugging efforts.

Comment: @OP since each decimal digit is also a hexidecimal digit if you print each digit of 109 with its hex value you'll get 109